# Como asociar el resultado de una consulta en LINQ al dataSource de un dataGridView

Tags: c#, linq, conversión-de-tipos

tengo un `dataGridView` con el resultado de una consulta, este `dataGridView` me permite seleccionar los registros que quiero:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var values = 
        from DataGridViewRow row in ewgrid1.Rows
        where Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["colCheck"].Value) == true
        select new {id = row.Cells[1],nombre=row.Cells[2] };

    frmResult formResultat = new frmResult();
    formResultat.data = values.ToList();
    
    formResultat.Show();

}
```

La idea es asociar el resultado de esta consulta en el grid del formulario `frmResult`, pero no se con que tipo de datos recogerlo y asociarlo al `dataSource` del `dataGridView`

El frmResult:

```
  public partial class frmResult : Form
    {
        public object data { get; set; }
        public frmResult()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frmResult_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ewgrid1.DataSource = data;
        }
    }
```

Esperando el resultado de la Select como tipo genérico `object` tal y como está en el código, es lo más cerca que he estado a que funcione, pero no se en que tipo de datos colocar el resultado para que funcione.
Me podéis ayudar por favor ?

Comment: ¿Te marca algun error?.

Answer (score 0):

¿No puedes configurar el RowFilter en algo como

```
dataView.RowFilter = "colCheck = true";
```

en lugar de construir esa consulta linq?